# Tag score over 100k causes minor bug

Tags: bug, tags, design, profile-page, tag-score

If someone has a tag score of over 100k, then the score will partly disappear under the tag itself on the user profile:

[image: bug]

I think there is only one user that has ever reached a tag score of over 100k, but of course we hope that once more users will reach this amazing accomplishment and we don't want to say 'thanks' by causing an error.

I found this on StackOverflow if it wasn't obvious.

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=topactivity)

Comment: It was reported already.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a set `width` of 25px in the CSS.

To fix it, changing `.user-show-new .user-tags .answer-votes,.user-show-new .user-badges .answer-votes`'s `width` attribute to `min-width` works:

> [image]

(line 11430 in `all.css`)

Comment: You said: To fix it, changing .user-show-new .user-tags .answer-votes,.user-show-new .user-badges .answer-votes's width attribute to min-width works.  Is that something I can do in my own settings, or is it directed to a developer?

Comment: @wythagoras directed to a developer - but Ilmari Karonen is known for [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/q/4486/26088) so if he comes before a developer, he *might* add it in which case you can install SOUP for yourself to get a bunch of other fixes as well!

Comment: By the way, how can you access all.css?

Comment: @wythagoras either just look up the url from source and download it, or use the tools built into just about every browser ;p

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflow/all.css is for SO. Use dev tools

Comment: @wythagoras for example, in chrome: http://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Idw.png

Comment: @MarcGravell I see, thank you.

Comment: yep do what @MarcGravell said - in Chrome, right click the element, click `Inspect element` and look to the right hand side

Comment: changing `width` to `min-width` actually has a lot of impact on the layout; I suspect it'll be a bit more involved than just that...

Comment: @MarcGravell It seemed to only increase a bit of space between the text and tag - sorry - didn't see any other changes when I answered! It might actually impact layout on other pages using the same class...